# Know if a type can be converted to string representing the data

Tags: c#, string, serialization

All C# types have the `ToString()` method inherited from the `object` base class. 
Sometimes, it returns a valuable string representation of the data, and sometimes something like the name of the type.

Is there a way to know if the `ToString()` method will return a string representation of the value data of the class ?

---

The context of my work about a custom serializer, that will use the string representation of the type if it is valuable, and if not a base 64 string of the `byte[]` values from the class.

Comment: You should deserialize complex type-members as well

Comment: You might be able to compare the output of the instance's `ToString()` method with the output `.Type().ToString()` to determine whether it's just outputting the type name instead of something useful. Not sure how useful using ToString() for serialization is, but that's probably something for you to decide depending on your requirements :-)

Comment: @Felipe : thanks for showing the duplicate question, with good answers.

Comment: @Diado : yes it is the trick.

Comment: @Stefan : thanks you helped me anticipate a bug, I will add a flag